# Purpose of jmp short after port I/O in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

In the process of reverse engineering an IDE controller's option ROM, I've noticed that every `in` or `out` instruction is followed by two `jmp short` instructions which simply jump to the next instruction (opcode `EB00`), like so:

```
    out dx, al
    jmp short next1
next1:
    jmp short next2
next2:
    ; code continues
```

What exactly is the reasoning behind this pattern?

Comment: To provide a small delay. It used to be devices required a delay between accessing their ports. On a 8086 each of these jumps would take 15 cycles to execute.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To allow the I/O device to process the previous data being sent to it before next data arrives, when CPU's began to run at more speed than what the I/O device could cope with. It is(was) used frequently with the PIT timer (8253) in which two 8-bit OUT's were necessary to write a 16-bit value in one of the three timers of the chip.

Besides, it was necessary because the original PC architecture didn't use the READY signal to stop the CPU until a I/O device had finished processing data, so the wait had to be performed in software. JMP fits well because it introduce a queue flush so the CPU wasted some cycles performing the actual jump.